# Where does OS X get defaults from in Guest User Web access Parental Controls?

Tags: security, websites, parental-controls, guest-account

I did not put these here, I don't know where they came from. WHOIS by IP seems to indicate they are from Amsterdam? (149.154.175.50 copy-pastable for anyone who wants to check)

[image]

Comment: Researching that IP is weird, depending on what database is used it tracks to London or Ukraine.  Do you have an app called Telegram or Telegram messenger?  https://telegram.org/

Comment: @Tyson that was it, though I still wonder where the defaults are pulled from

Comment: That app is poorly built. It should not rely on hard coded IP addresses.  It should look them up and cache them for some time value.   There is more than one online that complaint about that.  Maybe they will learn, from what I read it also looked like some of their servers have experienced DDOS attacks...with hard coded IPs they have to re-release the app to change them.  Anyway I'll type up an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using online tools it appears that as of this date/time that is a hard coded IP address from the app called Telegram or Telegram Messenger.

Why it's hard coded into the app as IP address doesn't make sense, but it seems to be where it is coming from.

Comment: Sure but this is an OS X settings app, it must be pulling it from somewhere? Unless the Telegram app injected them there, but then the question remains: "injected where?".